# Trying to write shell script under Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file which contains data like this:

```
1;2;3
4;5;6
7;8;9
....
n
```

where n is a random numer of lines. I'm trying to get from this file something like this:

```
command_1_command_2_command_3
command_4_command_5_command_6
....
n
```

Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks easy to do with `awk`. Give it a try, and post what you have if you can't get it working.

Comment: Does the file really contain bullets at the beginning of each line?

Comment: Of course not. I had problems with text formatting - now It's correct :)

Comment: It should also be simple using `sed`. Replace the beginning of the line with `command_`, and replace `;` with `_command_`.

Comment: Thx. Will try this tomorrow morning @ work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}; {$1="command_"$1;$2="command_"$2;$3="command_"$3;print $1"_"$2"_"$3}' stacko.txt

nachiket@nachiket-X550LD:~$ cat stacko.txt 
1;2;3
4;5;6
7;8;9
nachiket@nachiket-X550LD:~$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}; {$1="command_"$1;$2="command_"$2;$3="command_"$3;print $1"_"$2"_"$3}' stacko.txt 
command_1_command_2_command_3
command_4_command_5_command_6
command_7_command_8_command_9
nachiket@nachiket-X550LD:~$
```